# How to pivot two rows into two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following SQL Query:

```
select
    distinct

    Equipment_Reserved.Equipment_Attached_To,
    Equipment.Name
from
    Equipment,
    Studies,
    Equipment_Reserved
where
    Studies.Study = 'MAINT19-01'
    and
    Equipment.idEquipment = Equipment_Reserved.Equipment_idEquipment
    and
    Studies.idStudies = Equipment_Reserved.Studies_idStudies
    and
    Equipment.Type = 'Probe'
```

This query produces the following results:

```
Equipment_Attached_To   Name
2297                    R1-P1
2297                    R1-P2
2299                    R1-P3
```

I would like to change it to the following:

```
Equipment_Attached_To   Name1     Name2
2297                    R1-P1     R1-P2
2299                    R1-P3     NULL
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You don't want to `UNPIVOT`, you want to `PIVOT`. The question would be if you'll always have one or two rows? What happens if it has three or more?

Comment: Thanks, Luis.  I will have anywhere from 1 to 2 for each entry, thus the NULL value I entered.  The only way I can think of doing it is in VB, but I would prefer to do it in the SQL statement.

Comment: Do you actually need `DISTINCT`? What does the underlying data look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd first change your query from the old, legacy JOIN syntax to an explicit join as it makes the query easier to understand:

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT

    Equipment_Reserved.Equipment_Attached_To,
    Equipment.Name
FROM
    Equipment
    INNER JOIN Equipment_Reserved ON Equipment_Reserved.Equipment_idEquipment = Equipment.idEquipment
    INNER JOIN Studies            ON Studies.idStudies = Equipment_Reserved.Studies_idStudies

WHERE
    Studies.Study = 'MAINT19-01'
    AND
    Equipment.Type = 'Probe'
```

I don't think you actually need a `PIVOT` - I think you can do this with a nested query with the `ROW_NUMBER` function. I've seen that `PIVOT` queries often have worse query execution plans than nested-queries.

Let's add `ROW_NUMBER` (which require an `ORDER BY` as it's a windowing-function) and a matching `ORDER BY` in the whole query to make it consistent). Let's also use `PARTITION BY` so it resets the row-number for each `Equipment_Attached_To` value:

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT
    Equipment_Reserved.Equipment_Attached_To,
    Equipment.Name,

    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Equipment_Attached_To ORDER BY [Name]) AS RowNumber

FROM
    Equipment
    INNER JOIN Equipment_Reserved ON Equipment_Reserved.Equipment_idEquipment = Equipment.idEquipment
    INNER JOIN Studies            ON Studies.idStudies = Equipment_Reserved.Studies_idStudies

WHERE
    Studies.Study = 'MAINT19-01'
    AND
    Equipment.Type = 'Probe'

ORDER BY
    Equipment_Attached_To,
    [Name]
```

This will give output like this:

```
Equipment_Attached_To   Name    RowNumber
2297                    R1-P1    1
2297                    R1-P2    2
2299                    R1-P3    1
```

This can then be split out into explicit columns like so below. The use of `MAX()` is arbitrary (we could use `MIN()` instead) and only because we're dealing with a `GROUP BY` and because the `CASE WHEN...` restricts the input set to just 1 row anyway.

```
SELECT
    Equipment_Attached_To,
    MAX( CASE WHEN RowNumber = 1 THEN [Name] END ) AS Name1,
    MAX( CASE WHEN RowNumber = 2 THEN [Name] END ) AS Name2
FROM
    (
        -- the query from above
    )
GROUP BY
    Equipment_Attached_To
ORDER BY
    Equipment_Attached_To,
    Name1,
    Name2
```

So the final query is:

```
SELECT
    Equipment_Attached_To,
    MAX( CASE WHEN RowNumber = 1 THEN [Name] END ) AS Name1,
    MAX( CASE WHEN RowNumber = 2 THEN [Name] END ) AS Name2
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            DISTINCT
            Equipment_Reserved.Equipment_Attached_To,
            Equipment.Name,

            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Equipment_Attached_To ORDER BY [Name]) AS RowNumber

        FROM
            Equipment
            INNER JOIN Equipment_Reserved ON Equipment_Reserved.Equipment_idEquipment = Equipment.idEquipment
            INNER JOIN Studies            ON Studies.idStudies = Equipment_Reserved.Studies_idStudies

        WHERE
            Studies.Study = 'MAINT19-01'
            AND
            Equipment.Type = 'Probe'
    )
GROUP BY
    Equipment_Attached_To
ORDER BY
    Equipment_Attached_To,
    Name1,
    Name2
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much, Dai!  I really appreciate the improved syntax.  One issue - I am getting a Syntax issue for the GROUP BY statement in the last query.  Any ideas?

Comment: Hi @Dai, nevermind, I found the issue.  I added an "AS" after the ")" of the nested function.  Thank you so much, again!  I learned so much from your explanation to up my SQL game.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with some basics.

- To facilitate reading the code, I added alias to the tables using their initials.
- Then, I converted the old join syntax which is partly deprecated to use the standard syntax since 1992 (27 years and people still use the old syntax).
- Finally, since there are only 2 possible values, we can use `MIN` and `MAX` to separate them in 2 columns.
- And because we're using aggregate functions, we remove the `DISTINCT` and use `GROUP BY`
  The code now looks like this:

```
    SELECT er.Equipment_Attached_To, 
        --Gets the first row for the id
        MIN( e.Name) AS Name1, 
        --If the MAX is equal to the MIN, returns a NULL. If not, it returns the second value.
        NULLIF( MAX(e.Name), MIN( e.Name)) AS Name2 
    FROM Equipment e
    JOIN Studies s ON s.idStudies = er.Studies_idStudies
    JOIN Equipment_Reserved er ON e.idEquipment = er.Equipment_idEquipment
    WHERE s.Study = 'MAINT19-01'
    AND e.Type = 'Probe'
    GROUP BY er.Equipment_Attached_To;
```